# Call API only once when adding/removing subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I've a segmented control, clicking on segments shows views by adding view to a container view. When other segment control is clicked older view is removed and new view is added by using function given below. Adding VC in this way calls `viewDidLoad` where I fetch data from API. This calls API every time segment is clicked as VC is added. How do I prevent calling API every time view is added?

Is there any way we can hide old view instead of removing it, this will prevent instantiating VC every time a segment is clicked.

Alternatively is there any other better way to shows VCs on segment click?

```
@IBAction func show(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        let vc1 = VC1.instantiate()
        
        self.cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: self.currentVC!, toViewController: vc1)
        self.currentVC = vc1
           
    case 1:
        let vc2 = VC2.instantiate()
        self.cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: self.currentVC!, toViewController: vc2)
        self.currentVC = vc2
        
    default:
        break
            
    }
}


func cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: UIViewController, toViewController newViewController: UIViewController) {
    oldViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
    self.addChild(newViewController)
    self.addSubview(subView: newViewController.view, toView:self.containerView!)
    newViewController.view.alpha = 0
    newViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        newViewController.view.alpha = 1
        oldViewController.view.alpha = 0
    },
                   completion: { finished in
                    oldViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                    oldViewController.removeFromParent()
                    newViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create

```
var vc1,vc2,currentVC:UIViewController?
```

Then inside `viewDidLoad` create and assign `vc1` and `vc2` and set `currentVC = vc1`

after that play with their `view.isHidden`

Comment: So I add both VCs as subview first and then in show() show/hide them as required?

Comment: Works. Tx. Simple and effective, I should have thought of it earlier.